# Does the latest version of apache jackrabbit support Java 11?

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

Since upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11, the Jackrabbit JCR setup in my project has stopped working; it's either not saving or loading the data correctly (haven't quite figured that out yet).

I just wanted to double check that Jackrabbit JCR does support Java 11?

Comment: As their official website says (Java 8 or later).  https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html . I dont think its a Java related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does, as it's easily discoverable on http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html and http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jackrabbit-roadmap.html.

What version do you use?